Same product in multiple categories affects seo?
For example, a product called a thermostat is used in different categories like air conditioner, refrigerators, ice machine parts, oven parts. By categorizing thermostat to different categories, will it effect its SEO results?

It may help search engines determine more about the product. For example, is the product relevant to someone looking for a thermostat for a water heater?
The links from the multiple category pages will help create that association.
It would also help your users find the right product.

SEO doesn't care about your characterization of components.  Assuming everything else has been done right, then what matters is

How you are using it in a page (or pages)
How much duplication of text and image is between pages

It would be advisable to

Keep the usage, real or natural in the pages
Reduce the percentage of duplicated content between pages.
You could have a separate page for thermostats that is referred to, from other pages.

